# password program to mask characters-What's Wrong?

Tags: c++, c++11

I have written a program to show password as (*) like we normally get to see but I don't know what's wrong with it as it stops just after 3 character's input.... please help..

```
#include <iostream>
#include<string.h>
#include<conio.h>

using namespace std;

int main(){
char* pass=new char[20];
int i=0;
cout<<"\n\n Pass : ";
while(pass[i]!='\0')
{
    pass[i]=getch();
    i++;
    cout<<"*";

}

cout<<"\n\n";

if(strcmp(pass,"Vivek")==0)
{
    cout<<"Access Granted! "<<endl;
}
else
{
    cout<<"Access Denied!";
}
return 0;
}
```

The changes done have been described in the summary section..

```
//New code based on the discussions below

#include <iostream>
#include<string.h>
#include<conio.h>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
char pass[20];
int i=0;
cout<<"\n\n Pass : ";
do
{
    pass[i]=getch();
    i++;
    cout<<"*";

}while(pass[i-1]!='\0');
cout<<"\n\n";

if(strcmp(pass,"Vivek")==0)
{
    cout<<"Access Granted! "<<endl;
}
else
{
    cout<<"Access Denied!";
}
return 0;
}
```

Comment: You need to post the code.

Comment: You probably want to change that `while ()` loop into a `do {} while()` loop.

Comment: @Cornstalks still its not working properly.

Comment: There's no need to dynamically allocate the `char` array. `char pass[20];` will work just fine here.

Comment: The contents of the array that `pass` points to are not initialized, so any test you do on `pass[i]` is meaningless. You mention that you changed the loop do a `do ... while` loop, but haven't shown the code. If the test is looking at `pass[i]` after the `i++` it's still testing uninitialized memory. Instead, look at `pass[i-1]`, since that's where the input went.

Comment: Reminder:  text in C++ is case sensitive, so "vivek" is not equal to "Vivek".  If you use `std::string`, you could use a statement like `if (pass != "Vivek")`.

Comment: @Pete i have changed the while loop to do while so i don't think there is any need now to check on pass[i-1]. Anyways thanku because i was doing it wrong previously according to the code in the post...

Comment: @Thomas i want my string to match exactly with "Vivek" i.e. 'V' should be in capital and rest of the all letters should be small. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

In your loop, you are checking the slot for '\0' *before you put any value into the slot*.

```
while(pass[i]!='\0')
{
    pass[i]=getch();
    i++;
    cout<<"*";
}
```

Before entering the loop for the first time, the value of `i` is zero.  This translates to:

```
while (pass[0] != '\0')
```

According to your initialization, you have not initialized `pass[0]` or any of the slots in `pass` array.

The value *may* be zero, or it could be 2016.  You should *always* initialize variables before you use them, including arrays.

You will need to rethink how the loop will terminate.  For example, when the User presses Enter, what is the value returned by `getch()`?  Is it '\0'?

Also, to prevent buffer overflow (example, User inputting 30 characters), you should use the C++ `std::string` type.  If you insist on using C-style character arrays, your input loop should check for buffer overflow.

You should handle the case of backspace also (and don't forget buffer *underflow* checking).

Comment: thanku sir but still it has changed to unfinite loop